# Need resources in trying to install React-Native on WSL

Tags: react-native, installation, npm-install, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to figure out how to install react-native for WSL.  Unfortunately, a lot of the articles or guides I've seen are from mostly 2017.  A lot of articles point to having xcode installed, but for that I cannot find suitable tutorials to install xcode on WSL.  I am not really sure how to proceed.  I know after having xcode installed I should proceed to install expo-cli, but can't really find information to progress from A to B.  Any ideas on how I can successfully install react-native on WSL?

Comment: Hello just follow the same procedure for a Linux installation. Install in WSL is the same as installing on Linux

Answer (score -2):

I would strongly suggest you install expo-cli on your WSL, so the workflow would be:

1. Install your WSL favorite version (I've used Ubuntu).
2. Install libraries and packages to develop a react-native app (nvm, node,
   yarn, vscode).
3. Install expo-cli tools, you can find the steps here:
   https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/
4. Create your app and open it with vscode ( code /react-native-path).
5. Start to code :)